# What is the best way to authenticate your springboot application?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I was wondering about the best way to secure your spring boot application in a dynamic way,

I am using my own authorization server using spring security with one client (app) now I should configure again to have dynamic clients,

It's not that hard but it made me questioning whether the spring auth server is the best option or I should go to Keycloak for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> best way to secure your spring boot application

The best way to use authentication in spring based application is using spring security. Now it depends on your use-case  that you should authenticate user from application database, LDAP or Active Directory, in-memory authentication.

> using my own authorization server using spring security with one client (app) now I should configure again to have dynamic clients

I believe you meant authentication instead of authorization in above line. You can stick to spring security by building admin console for user management. Both authentication and authorization can be managed from admin console. But as said before it is completely your use-case.

- If your usecase says that app-users are already logging in
  centralized Active Directory and they dont need to login again for
  your application, implement Spring security with LDAP and SSO.
- If your usecase say that there is no centralized authentication server and appuser details are very specific to you application, implement Spring securirty with database authentication